# Result of SQL query gives strange result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One is called Sales and the other one is called Uren. Each entry in the Sales table represents one sale with the date (finalized_at) when the sale has been made and each entry in the Uren table represents a shift worked by the agent containing the hours worked and the date (datum) when the shift was. The tables look like this:

Sales table

```
+-------+--------------+
| agent | finalized_at |
+-------+--------------+
| John  | 01-01-2020   |
+-------+--------------+
| John  | 02-01-2020   |
+-------+--------------+
| Mark  | 01-01-2020   |
+-------+--------------+
| Peter | 01-01-2020   |
+-------+--------------+
| John  | 04-01-2020   |
+-------+--------------+
```

Uren table

```
+-------+-------+------------+
| agent | hours | datum      |
+-------+-------+------------+
| John  | 1     | 01-01-2020 |
+-------+-------+------------+
| John  | 5     | 02-01-2020 |
+-------+-------+------------+
| Mark  | 1     | 01-01-2020 |
+-------+-------+------------+
| Peter | 2     | 01-01-2020 |
+-------+-------+------------+
| John  | 4     | 04-01-2020 |
+-------+-------+------------+
```

In order to calculate the commission of the agents on the 4th of january I have to take in account the performance of the agent of the rest of the month. In order to do that I need to calculate the sales per hour of the whole month, but only of the agents who made a sale on the 4th of january.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT agent, (SELECT SUM(case when finalized_at BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-01-31 23:59:59' AND agent=Sales.agent then 1 else 0 end) FROM Sales WHERE agent=Sales.agent AND finalized_at BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-01-31 23:59:59')/(SELECT SUM(uren) FROM Uren WHERE datum BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-01-31 23:59:59' AND agent=Sales.agent) as sph FROM Sales WHERE finalized_at BETWEEN '2020-01-04 00:00:00' AND '2020-01-04 23:59:59' GROUP BY agent ORDER by sph DESC;
```

For some reason when running the query the second column (sales) returns the total amount of lines in the Sales table instead of using the where clausule as stated.

So my question is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can try this `SELECT agent,
       sales,
       sales/s_uren AS sph
FROM
  (SELECT s.agent,
          COUNT(*) AS sales,
          SUM(uren) s_uren
   FROM Sales s,
        Uren u
   WHERE u.agent=s.agent
   GROUP BY u.agent) r
ORDER BY 3 DESC ;` This will calculate everythign first then calculate the required data.

Comment: `SUM(uren)`?  should it be `SUM(hours)`?

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of subqueries referencing `Sales` table

```
SELECT agent,
       COUNT(*) AS sales,
       COUNT(*) /
                ( SELECT SUM(uren) 
                    FROM Uren 
                   WHERE agent = s.agent) AS sph
  FROM Sales AS s
 GROUP BY agent
 ORDER by sph DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would pre-query each table separately by the respective agent and join them.

```
SELECT 
      AgentHrs.Agent,
      AgentHrs.TotHours,
      coalesce( AgentCnt.NumberSales, 0 ) NumberSales,
      coalesce( AgentCnt.NumberSales, 0 ) / AgentHrs.TotHours as sph
  FROM 
     ( select agent, SUM(uren) TotHours
          from uren
          group by agent ) AgentHrs
     LEFT JOIN
        ( select agent, count(*) NumberSales
             from Sales
             group by agent ) AgentCnt
           on AgentHrs.Agent = AgentCnt.Agent
   ORDER BY 
      sph DESC;
```

I put the prequery of agent hours summarization first here because you probably can not have a sale unless you have worked.  So the hours would have to be guaranteed.  Second is a LEFT-JOIN to actual sales.  Just because someone works does not mean they WILL get a sale.  So you could have 0 sales over 4 hours and you have 0 sales per hour.

Answer (score 0):

A `union all` is a simple approach:

```
select agent, sum(sales), sum(hours), sum(sales) / sum(hours
from ((select agent, 1 as sales, 0 as hours
       from sales
      ) union all
      (select agent, 0, hours
       from uren
      )
     ) us
group by agent;
```